# Mavericks Instalation freeze! - please advice. Progress Bar not moving

Tags: osx-mavericks

It says "Time remaining: About 39 minutes" or it goes to 42, then 36, but the blue progress bar doesn't move.

I've wait more than 1 hour, and the progress bar is still there.

i reboot, and the same thing occours again. Progress bar freeze.

What can I do?

I wish NOT to loose the data there present.

Should I re-install Lion a d download Mavericks again?

I've no time machine backup. that thing never worked for me.

Any faster option?

Please advice!

Comment: Contacted Apple Genius Bar? (Maverick is .. JUST released.. I doubt anyone know any better.. unless they work with Apple and maybe already trained for this situation)

Comment: perhaps previous similar issues with older osx could be of any help.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery? (Also, that teaches a valuable lesson about making backups before doing OS upgrades..)

Comment: I boot into recovery by doing: cmd+r+p is that it? I've done that and I select reinstall mac os x. it freezes there as well!! :(

Comment: the progress bar. not the computer.

Comment: No dice. I have tried to restore the old OS, no luck either. I end up removing the partition and install the old OS and then, Mavericks was able to be installed. About the time-machine backup, well, at least on my laptop, it gets really, really, slow and responsiveness while doing backups. So, at the very end, I've never use it because it wasn't practical. I happen to lost all the information there present (2 years work), because I didn't want to wait/have some Apple Genius to look into my stored data, nor open the laptop disk and retrieve the data there present. All this to say: Stay Warned.